# Sqlite "Update" C# Syntax Error

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, syntax

Hi following Code gives a Syntax Error.I don't know how to fix the Problem.

The Error

> {"SQLite error\r\nnear \"Mytext\": syntax error"}

My Code

```
string dataSource = "Database.s3db";
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;
connection.Open();
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
command.CommandText = ("update Example set Info ='" + textBox2.Text + ", Text ='"+textBox3.Text + "where ID ='" + textBox1.Text +"'");
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: To avoid this kind of errors (and SQL injections), you should use query parameters, not create the SQL command string dynamically.

Comment: @user1248067: *Please* don't use the accepted answer as-is. You should *really, really* use parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Others have suggested alternative ways of constructing the SQL, but you shouldn't be including the values in the SQL at all. You should be using a parameterized query, which avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) amongst other things.

It's not immediately clear to me which driver you're using, but assuming it's the Devart.com one, the documentation for [`SQLiteCommand.Parameters`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand~Parameters.html) gives a good example of how to do this. In your case, the code would become something like:

```
string dataSource = "Database.s3db";
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;
    connection.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        command.CommandText =
            "update Example set Info = :info, Text = :text where ID=:id";
        command.Parameters.Add("info", DbType.String).Value = textBox2.Text; 
        command.Parameters.Add("text", DbType.String).Value = textBox3.Text; 
        command.Parameters.Add("id", DbType.String).Value = textBox1.Text; 
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a version issue; but I had to use "DbType.String" in place of "SqLiteType.Text". I'm using SQLite version 1.0.99

Answer (score 1):

So, use the above answer as parameterised SQL is best practice.

But, to answer your question on syntax - there's two issues:

`command.CommandText = ("update Example set Info ='" + textBox2.Text + ", Text ='"+textBox3.Text + "where ID ='" + textBox1.Text +"'");`

Here, you're not closing the single quote after you've written the
`set Info ='" + textBox2.Text + ", Text`

It should be:
`set Info ='" + textBox2.Text + "', Text`

^^ with a closing ' after the double quote.

You've made same mistake with textBox3.

Also, `Text ='"+textBox3.Text + "where`

There's no space before the where keyword.

Tip: when having errors like this, output SQL to console & inspect string constructed. But parameterised is best approach.